How to cancel sql query after some time in python
Look at this code:
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
cnxn.commit()

Usually this code works fine. But there are certain querys which take an infinite time to be executed. This is not a python problem. When I execute them using SQL Server Management Studio I have the same behavior. But there I have the possibility to cancel the query when I'm sick of waiting. I'm looking for an analogue possibility in python. Can I tell python somehow to try it for maybe 10 minutes and cancel then? How do I do taht?

You could try running the SQL query in a child process that can be cancelled after a certain period of time if it hasn't completed. For instance:
import pyodbc
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    cnxn.commit()

def main():
    p = Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
    # Wait for up to 10 minutes for the process to complete:
    p.join(600)  # 600 seconds
    # Did the process actually complete?
    if p.exitcode is None:
        # The process is still running after 600 second, so:
        p.terminate()  # Kill the process
        print('Process killed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

